# In Cognos 10.2.1 - how can I use substring portions of an input parameter to create an expression to use for date comparison?

Tags: cognos-10

In Cognos 10.2.1 (FP7), I have a situation with two tables (see below), where a given transaction may be in the same "PERIOD", but what I want to do is to only give me results for transactions that have a date after the 15th of the month (i.e - the transaction may be in PERIOD 201510, and I only want transactons on/after 10/15/2015).  The PERIOD is an input parameter that the user selects - I want to build the date from a portion of the PERIOD.  (Before anyone complains about syntax, etc. - I've tried to simplify this as much as possible).

Given Table A:

```
ID              varchar
PERIOD          varchar
```

Given Table B:

```
ID              varchar
TYPE            varchar 
TRANDATE        timestamp2
```

Query1

```
[A.PERIOD]=?PARM1?  <- this is the user selected input parameter
```

Query2

```
[B.TYPE] in ('A','B')
```

Then create a join from the results of Query1 and Query2 on the A.ID=B.ID to give Results1

I've tried the following (I'm keeping this as simple as I can - so I'm ONLY working with the YEAR portion of the period):

```
[Results1].[TRANDATE] >= concat(substring([Results1].[PERIOD],1,4),'-10-15T00:00:00.000000000')

[Results1].[TRANDATE] >= cast(concat(substring([Results1].[PERIOD],1,4),'-10-15T00:00:00.000000000'), timestamp2)
```

In both cases - Cognos won't validate the expression, or, if it does validate, I get a runtime error when running the report.  In both cases, I get messages basically "literal does not match format string", even with the cast.

So - how can I get pieces/portions of the parameter, and slice/dice them to use as a date comparison as I mentioned above?

Comment: I might add that when comparing to a literal string, I can use the format: '2016-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'  just fine, and that works in the query.  I simply want to "parameterize" it, based on another parm.

Answer (score 0):

Given: Column [PERIOD] of type integer in the form YYYYMM, [TRANDATE] of type date/time

```
[TRANDATE] >= cast(cast(cast([PERIOD]/100,integer),varchar(4)) || '-' || cast(mod([PERIOD],100),varchar(2)) || '-15',date)
```

Given: Column [PERIOD] of type string in the form 'YYYYMM', [TRANDATE] of type date/time

```
[TRANDATE] >= cast(substring([PERIOD],1,4) || '-'  || substring([PERIOD],5,2) || '-15',date)
```

The trick is that you don't have to build a full date/time string. You only have to build a string of format 'YYYY-MM-DD' in order to cast to a date type.